# C# operator \n for string in HTML &#10; &#13; not working

Tags: html, django, string, hyperlink, line-breaks

Website on Django 3.2, Visual Studio 2019. It is necessary to transfer the text of the link description - a text string in the HTML code. There are special HTML codes `&#10;` `&#13;` for line feed and carriage return. Their use does not give the desired result. `<br>` - is working: `<a href="link">Text3.<br>Text4.</a>`. But why HTML special codes not working?

```
{% extends "/layout.html" %}<!--♕-->{% block content %}<div class="Jambotron">
<h1>Welcome!</h1>
<p class="lead">Text1!&#10;&#13;Text2.</p>
<a href="link">Text3.&#10;&#13;Text4.</a>
</div>{% endblock %}
```

Example: special codes HTML did not work out as intended

[image: Example: special codes did not work out as intended]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML, multiple whitespace characters are collapsed to a single space by default.
This is a great "feature", since it allows you to write your markup with readable indentation etc.

However, you can control this behaviour with the CSS property `white-space` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space).

To preserve your special whitespace characters you can use `white-space: pre;`

```css
p {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<p class="lead">Text1!&#10;&#13;Text2.</p>
```